# Julia Stochastic Differential Equation Very Slow

Tags: performance, optimization, julia, differential-equations, stochastic-process

Please help me figure out why my code is sooo slow and possible ways to speed it up. I have used vectorization, @inbounds, column major indexing, @floop, and preallocation so I would think it would be faster. I am at a loss...

The code simulates a stochastic wave of cells (as in biological cells) and mutant cells. I am using the Euler-Murayama method to propagate the coupled (Chemical Langevin) equations:

[image: Wild CLE]
[image: Mutant CLE]

Where W/M denotes the number of wild-type cells and mutant cells respectively, K is the carrying capacity (maximum number of cells), i denotes the deme (location), and N(0,1) is a normal random variable.

Here is a graphic of the waves after some time propagating:

[image: Wild Wave]

I have attached the important part of the code below, and tried to comment it as best as I could.

```
using Random, Distributions
using StatsBase
using Statistics
using FLoops

# CLE Parameters/Set-Up:
K = 100 # Carrying capacity (maximum number of cells)
M = 100 # Number of demes (locations)
T = 100_000_000 # number of time steps
dt = 1e-1 # time increment
g = Normal(0.0,sqrt(dt)) # normal distribution with ave = 0.0, std_dev = dt
r_w = 0.1 # Wild-type growth rate
r_m = 0.2 # Mutant growth rate
r_wm = [r_w, r_m]' # Growth rate vector (transposed)
N = 1 # number of independent processes (slow even when N = 1)

# initial wave (essentially a step-function of wild-types 
# with 100 mutants at deme (location) 76)
state_init = Matrix(reshape(repeat([K, 0.0]',M+2),(M+2,2))) 
state_init[M÷2+2:end,1] .= 0   
state_init[76,2] = 100.0
state_init[1,:] .= [K,0]
state_init[end,:] .= [0,0]

state = deepcopy(state_init)
state_plus = zeros(size(state_init)) # state at demes i+1 instead of i (used for derivatives)
state_minus = zeros(size(state_init)) # state at demes i-1 instead of i (used for derivatives)

function sim!(state_init::Matrix{Float64}, state::Matrix{Float64},
              T::Int64, dt::Float64, N::Int64, M::Int64, K::Int64,
              hist_data::Array{Int64,3}, g::Normal{Float64})

    @inbounds @floop for n in 1:N
        state .= deepcopy(state_init) # initialize state
        @inbounds for t in 1:T
            
            state_plus .= circshift(state, -1) # make plus state
            state_plus[1,:] .= [0,0] # fix boundary conditions
            state_minus .= circshift(state, 1) # make minus state
            state_minus[end,:] .= [0,0] # fix boundary conditions
            state_shift = circshift(state, (0,1)) 
            # make state where each deme has a vector 
            # (# mutants, # wild-types) instead of 
            # (# wild-types, # mutants)

            ######################################
            # propagate state using Euler-Murayama method and
            # restrict number of cells in a deme to be in the range [0,K]
            # using clamp(). clamp() also prevents imaginary numbers from 
            # a negative number under the sqrt().

            state .= clamp.(state .+ 
            dt .* (r_wm .* state .* (K .- state .- state_shift) .+ 
            K .* (state_plus .- 2.0 .* state .+ state_minus)) .+ 
            sqrt.(clamp.(
            6 .* state .* (K .- state) .+ 
            (K .- 2.0 .* state) .* (state_plus .- 2.0 .* state .+ 
            state_minus) .- r_wm .* state .* (K .- state .- state_shift), 
            0.0, 1.0*K*K)) .* 
            rand(g,M+2), 0.0, 1.0*K) 
            ######################################

        end
    end
end

sim!(state_init, state, T, dt, N, M, K, hist_data, g)


... the rest of the code is analysis and not the reason the code is slow.
```

Comment: Put all the code in a function and call that function. Global variables (ones defines in the REPL or not inside function) are too dynamic in nature to be properly optimized for. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: It helped a bit :) It went from about 50 minutes to about 40 minutes runtime. I am hoping there is still something I can do.

Comment: There is still much to optimize after using suggestions in answer. First off, the `deepcopy` is unnecessary as the values are assigned to an existing array. Furthermore, there is at least 3 copy operations on the `state` which can probably be reduced to at most 1. Perhaps giving shorter variable names will make the code look more compact and easier to reason about - for example, the propagation step at each loop has a long multi-line expression which will become shorter with small variables names.

Comment: It seems to be coming together now :) Thank you all so much for the help! I've changed the way the code is implemented by referencing state[2:end-1,1], state[1:end-2,1], and state[3:end,1] instead of state, state_minus, and state_plus. I think this solves a lot of the slow down.

Comment: Make sure to use `@views` when you do that. `state[2:end-1,1]` allocates new memory to contain that part of the array. Placing `@views` at the beginning of the line changes such array-slice accesses to use pieces of the original array itself (providing "view"s into the original array), so avoids that allocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you're pre-allocating `state_plus` and `state_minus`, memory is being allocated inside the for loop since you're using `circshift` instead of `circshift!`. `circshift` allocates new memory regardless of the fact that it's ultimately being assigned to an existing pre-allocated array. Doing that allocation 300 million times is bound to be costly!

Try

```
function sim!(state_init::Matrix{Float64}, state::Matrix{Float64},
              T::Int64, dt::Float64, N::Int64, M::Int64, K::Int64,
              hist_data::Array{Int64,3}, g::Normal{Float64})

    @inbounds @floop for n in 1:N
        state .= deepcopy(state_init) # initialize state
        state_plus = zeros(size(state_init)) # state at demes i+1 instead of i (used for derivatives)
        state_minus = zeros(size(state_init)) # state at demes i-1 instead of i (used for derivatives)
        state_shift = zeros(size(state_init)) 

        for t in 1:T
            
            circshift!(state_plus, state, -1) # make plus state
            state_plus[1,:] .= [0,0] # fix boundary conditions
            circshift!(state_minus, state, 1) # make minus state
            state_minus[end,:] .= [0,0] # fix boundary conditions
            circshift!(state_shift, state, (0,1))
```

and

```
function sim!(state_init::Matrix{Float64}, state::Matrix{Float64},
              T::Int64, dt::Float64, N::Int64, M::Int64, K::Int64,
              hist_data::Array{Int64,3}, g::Normal{Float64})

    state_plus = zeros(size(state_init)) # state at demes i+1 instead of i (used for derivatives)
    state_minus = zeros(size(state_init)) # state at demes i-1 instead of i (used for derivatives)
    state_shift = zeros(size(state_init)) 
    @inbounds for n in 1:N
        state .= deepcopy(state_init) # initialize state
        for t in 1:T
            
            circshift!(state_plus, state, -1) # make plus state
            state_plus[1,:] .= [0,0] # fix boundary conditions
            circshift!(state_minus, state, 1) # make minus state
            state_minus[end,:] .= [0,0] # fix boundary conditions
            circshift!(state_shift, state, (0,1))
```

The second version doesn't use `@floop`, but that allows it to not have to initialize `state_plus` and others `N` times, so it *may* be the case that it's faster for your actual `N`. Best to try both and find out!

Comment: I see, thank you :) I've changed the way the code is implemented by referencing state[2:end-1,1], state[1:end-2,1], and state[3:end,1] instead of state, state_minus, and state_plus. I think this solves a lot of the slow down.